# Add dataset values as numbers correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add the data of some data-attributes within a simple formula. But the values don't get interpreted as numbers, but as strings. I do it like that:

```
 var nutzer = document.getElementById('chosen_meals').getElementsByTagName('p');
 var kalorien = 0;
 for (var i = 0; i < amountOfMeals_low; i++) {
     var kalorien = kalorien + nutzer[i].dataset.kal;
     console.log(kalorien);
 }
```

And the markup is some like that

```html
<ul id="chosen_meals">
  <li>
    <p data-kal="420">Foo</p>
  </li>
  <li>
    <p data-kal="180">Foo</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

And I do get logged 
0
0420
0420180

How would I get it to be the result of 600?

Comment: Perhaps casting it as a number: `var kalorien = kalorien + Number(nutzer[i].dataset.kal)`.

Comment: @user4642212 You are correct. I will delete that comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to convert it using `Number` or `parseInt`
e.g. 
`Number(nutzer[i].dataset.kal)`